# Remove this section of code and put it into another loop

Tags: php, wordpress

I've been racking my brain for weeks trying to remove this block of code, it's from paid memberships pro plugin.

I need to remove the below section as it produces the file fields on the user profile.

need to remove it and put it in a loop of its own and then print it, as I need it to be in a separate `<section>` from the rest of the fields that are in that original loop.

```
//----Trying to remove this piece of code----//

?>
<strong><?php echo $field[0]; ?></strong>
<div class="Test"><?php echo pmpromd_display_file_field($meta_field); ?></div>
<?php 


//---This is the FullSnippet with the above code included----//



if(!empty($fields_array))
                   {
                       foreach($fields_array as $field)
                       {

                           if(empty($field[0]))
                               break;

                           // Fix for a trailing space in the 'fields' shortcode attribute.
                           if ( $field[0] === ' ' ) {
                               break;
                           }

                           $field_val = $field[1];
                           $meta_field = $pu->$field_val;

                           if(!empty($meta_field))
                           {
                               ?>
                               <section class="pmpro_member_directory_<?php echo esc_attr($field[1]); ?>">
                               <?php
                                   if(is_array($meta_field) && !empty($meta_field['filename']) )
                                   {
                                       //this is a file field
                                       ?>
                                       <strong><?php echo $field[0]; ?></strong>
                                       <div class="brendan"><?php echo pmpromd_display_file_field($meta_field); ?></div>
                                       <?php
                                   }elseif(is_array($meta_field)){
                                       //this is a general array, check for Register Helper options first
                                       if(!empty($rh_fields[$field[1]])) {
                                           foreach($meta_field as $key => $value)
                                               $meta_field[$key] = $rh_fields[$field[1]][$value];
                                       }
                                       ?>

                                       <strong><?php echo $field[0]; ?></strong>
                                       <ul class="servicesList"><?php echo '<li>'.implode("</li>\n<li>",$meta_field).'</li>';?></ul>
                                       <?php
                                   }
                                   elseif(!empty($rh_fields[$field[1]])  && is_array($rh_fields[$field[1]]) )
                                   {
                                   ?>
                                       <strong><?php echo $field[0]; ?></strong>
                                       <?php echo $rh_fields[$field[1]][$meta_field]; ?>
                                       <?php
                                   }
                                   else
                                   {
                                       if($field[1] == 'user_url')
                                       {
                                           ?>
                                           <a href="<?php echo esc_url($meta_field); ?>" target="_blank"><?php echo $field[0]; ?></a>
                                           <?php
                                       }
                                       else
                                       {
                                           ?>
                                   <strong><?php echo $field[0]; ?></strong>
                                           <?php
                                               $meta_field_embed = wp_oembed_get($meta_field);
                                               if(!empty($meta_field_embed)){
                                                   echo $meta_field_embed;
                                               }else{
                                                   echo make_clickable($meta_field);
                                               }
                                           ?>
                                           <?php
                                       }
                                   }
                               ?>


                           </section>
                               <?php
                           }
                       }
                   }
               ?>
```

Comment: It seems those echo commands are in a middle of an if/else statement. What do you want to do in other branches of the if/else? What did you try and why did not work?

Comment: this code should be called via a function can you share that code?

Comment: This needs more context first (assuming you want to do it properly.) Does the plugin offer any hooks/filters around this functionality, that could be used to modify the output? Or the input data? This will probably boil down to that you’ll have to find a way to remove the “offending” entry/entries from `$fields_array`, and store them into a different variable, so that you can output them elsewhere later. Looks like `!empty($meta_field['filename'])` is the relevant criterion here that makes it decide to output that particular block of HTML, so you’d need to filter the array based on that.